# cordova-plugin-background-download not installed latest version

Tags: cordova

I have installed cordova plugin for downloading background file which is https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download. Latest version is 0.5.0 but after installing it is showing 0.0.2.

My latest
 cordova version : 9.0.0 
And Android SDK: 8.0.0

So How can i installed 0.5.0 version ?

I have also tried

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-download@0.5.0

And

cordova plugin add http://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download

none of the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0.2 is the latest released version on npm, as can be seen here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-download

To use 0.5.0, set the source as the github repository, as such:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-download" spec="git+https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-background-download.git" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Nikitah. Uninstalled old git version 1.9.5 and installed latest git 2.22.0.After that add plugin as -  cordova plugin add http://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download. Now it is working fine.